# Как спарсить участников чужой Telegram группы?

Tags: парсер, telegram-bot, telegram

Подскажите эффективный способ собрать имена, логины и номера всех участников Telegram группы.

У меня сейчас на заметке 3 варианта:

1. **Использовать web версию** telegram и написать JS скрипт. Но там отображаются только 200 участников.
2. **Использовать бота**. Но еще не изучил возможно ли это, если группа принадлежит не мне.
3. **Использовать стороннее ПО**. Пока что подходящего не нашел.

Буду благодарен, если поделитесь своим опытом. Возможно есть еще какие-то более эффективные варианты, или какой из моих выбрать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 - ботом нельзя, даже если группа твоя (разве что новых вступивших)

3 - стороннее по наверно есть, учитывая что пользователей собрать можно через клиентский аккаунт, используя тот же тдлиб. Так что если смотреть в сторону пункта 1, то практически на любом языке можно собирать имена и юзернеймы с групп, используя подходящую реализацию библиотеки для работы с тдлиб.

А вот номера не собрать